# replacing loop-based deduplication code with redshift SQL

Tags: r, loops, amazon-redshift, lag, dense-rank

We are trying to migrate a lot of legacy R code, which is used for data set manipulation, to redshift SQL.  All of it is easily ported, except for the below bit, which has proven intractable.  Which is why I'm coming to you, gentle SO reader.  I suspect what I'm asking is impossible, but I lack the ability to prove it.

What the below R code does is dedupe unique integer indentifiers by using a looping mechanism.  You'll see the full details in the inline comments.

Before we get to that, here is a small annotated example set to give you an idea of the impact that the desired SQL code should have:

[image]

Here is the annotated R code that we are trying to replace with redshift SQL:

```
# the purpose of this function is to dedupe a set of identifiers
    # so that each month, the set if identifiers grouped under that month
    # will not have appeared in the previous two months
    # it does this by building 3 sets:
        # current month
        # previous month
        # 2 months ago
        # In a loop, it sets the current month set for the current year-month value in the loop
            # then filters that set against the contents of previous 2 months' sets
            # then unions the surving months set against the survivors of previous months so far

# I believe the functionality below is mainly taken from library(dplyr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(multidplyr) 
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
library(RJDBC)

dedupeIdentifiers <- function(dataToDedupe, YearToStart = 2014, YearToEnd = 2016) { 
    # dataToDedupe is input set
    # YearToStart = default starting year
    # YearToEnd = default ending year

    monthYearSeq <- expand.grid(Month = 1:12, Year = YearToStart:YearToEnd) %>% tbl_df() # make a grid having all months 1:12 from starting to ending year
    twoMonthsAgoIdentifiers <- data_frame(propertyid = integer(0)) # make empty data frame to hold list of unique identifiers
    oneMonthAgoIdentifiers  <- data_frame(propertyid = integer(0)) # make empty data frame to hold list of unique identifiers
    identifiersToKeep <- dataToDedupe %>% slice(0) # make empty data frame to hold list of unique identifiers

    for(i in 1:nrow(monthYearSeq)) {
        curMonth <- monthYearSeq$Month[i] # get current month for row in loop of monthYearSeq
        curYear <- monthYearSeq$Year[i] # get current year for row in loop of monthYearSeq

        curIdentifiers <- dataToDedupe %>% filter(year(initialdate) == curYear, month(initialdate) == curMonth)%>% 
            # initialdate is the date variable in the set by which the set is filtered
            # start by filtering to make a subset, curIdentifiers, which is the set where initialdate == current month and year in the loop
            group_by(uniqueidentifier) %>% slice(1) %>% ungroup() %>%  # take just 1 example of each unique identifier in the subset
            anti_join(twoMonthsAgoIdentifiers) %>% # filter out uniqueidentifier that were in set two months ago
            anti_join(oneMonthAgoIdentifiers) # filter out uniqueidentifier that were in set one month ago

        twoMonthsAgoIdentifiers <- oneMonthAgoIdentifiers # move one month set into two month set
        oneMonthAgoIdentifiers <- curIdentifiers %>% select(uniqueidentifier) # move current month set into one month set
        identifiersToKeep <- bind_rows(identifiersToKeep, curIdentifiers) # add "surviving" unique identifiers after filtering for last 2 months
            # to updated set of deduped indentifiers
    } # lather, rinse, repeat

    return(identifiersToKeep) # return all survivors
}
```

Finally, here are some things that we have tried so far without success:

1. Recursive CTEs have been suggested.  Redshift does not allow recursive CTEs.
2. Use lags to assess the date diff between the "current" date value and previous date values, partitioned on the unique identifier.  This doesn't work in the case of say a continuous set of months 1-5 for the same unique identifier 123.  Both months 4&5 would be kept in that case but month 5 actually ought to be dropped.
3. Auto left-join the set against itself on the unique identifier, so that all month permutations can be evaluated.  -- This actually has the same problem as using lags.
4. Use a dummy date set with all desired months and years to inject missing months and years into the set to be filtered. Flag the rows that are from the original to-be-filtered set. Then use dense_rank, partitioned on the unique identifier and the flag, to select every row with rank % 3 =0. This has the problem that you can't always get the dense_rank value to count as needed across the partitions, so the % 3 value comes out wrong.
5. Use combinations of the above.
6. [Replacing loop with set-based operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753229/replacing-loop-with-set-based-operation).

We can get to ~90 % parity with the original looping code but unfortunately we have to have a perfect substitute.

Please do honor our objective to reproduce this in SQL, or to prove that reproducing the results of a loop, in this case, is impossible with SQL.  Responses like "just stick with R", "do the loop in python", "try this new package" won't be helpful.

Thanks so much for any positive advice.

Comment: how many values can you have with the same unique identifier? max?

Comment: Thanks @JonScott . I misprinted earlier: In a given month (based on initialdate), there should be just one instance of a unique identifier value, and that value should NOT have occurred in the previous 2 months.

Comment: It would be possible to use a redshift python UDF for this, for each row you can pass the current row data and an array of all of the previous values (which you can create in sql by joining to an array_agg summary subtable). The python then could apply the same complex logic that you have in R and return a flag to indicate whether the row should be kept.

Answer (score 1):

Your process can be completed in Redshift using "sql sessionization" techniques.

Essentially you use a number of LAG() statements to compare the data over your specific windows and then compare the results to complete the final classification.

- https://sonra.io/2017/08/14/redshifts-window-functions-advanced-use-case-sessionization/
- https://www.dataiku.com/learn/guide/code/reshaping_data/sessionization.html
- https://blog.modeanalytics.com/finding-user-sessions-sql/

Comment: Thanks! So far using lags has not worked, but I'll try this and see if it offers anything new.

Comment: Don't hesitate to use temporary or staging tables. Break the logic into simpler pieces. Also make sure to declare the dist key for the temp tables. It will speed up the final calculation if they all have the same distilled key.

Comment: The essence of these articles seems to be "flag the rows you want to keep/operate on using lag look-backs".  I haven't found an approach with lags yet that catches all the cases but I'll give it a shot.  Just so you know the full test of an approach with all the data is a bit involved so if I don't respond quickly that's why.  I'll see if I can dredge up some exceptions from past efforts where lags have not worked; maybe that will expose anything about your sessionization approach that I'm missing.